# Deleting an element from 3d matrix java

Tags: java, matrix

I have the following 3d matrix:

```
[0,1] | [0,2] | [1,0] | [1,1] | [1,2] | [2,0] | [2,1] | [2,2]
[0,0] | [0,2] | [1,0] | [1,1] | [1,2] | [2,0] | [2,1] | [2,2]
[0,0] | [0,1] | [1,0] | [1,1] | [1,2] | [2,0] | [2,1] | [2,2]
[0,0] | [0,1] | [0,2] | [1,1] | [1,2] | [2,0] | [2,1] | [2,2]
[0,0] | [0,1] | [0,2] | [1,0] | [1,2] | [2,0] | [2,1] | [2,2]
[0,0] | [0,1] | [0,2] | [1,0] | [1,1] | [2,0] | [2,1] | [2,2]
[0,0] | [0,1] | [0,2] | [1,0] | [1,1] | [1,2] | [2,1] | [2,2]
[0,0] | [0,1] | [0,2] | [1,0] | [1,1] | [1,2] | [2,0] | [2,2]
[0,0] | [0,1] | [0,2] | [1,0] | [1,1] | [1,2] | [2,0] | [2,1]
```

I want for example in the  line 6  delete [0,2]

And get the following output :

```
  [0,1] | [0,2] | [1,0] | [1,1] | [1,2] | [2,0] | [2,1] | [2,2]
  [0,0] | [0,2] | [1,0] | [1,1] | [1,2] | [2,0] | [2,1] | [2,2]
  [0,0] | [0,1] | [1,0] | [1,1] | [1,2] | [2,0] | [2,1] | [2,2]
  [0,0] | [0,1] | [0,2] | [1,1] | [1,2] | [2,0] | [2,1] | [2,2]
  [0,0] | [0,1] | [0,2] | [1,0] | [1,2] | [2,0] | [2,1] | [2,2]
  [0,0] | [0,1] | [1,0] | [1,1] | [2,0] | [2,1] | [2,2]
  [0,0] | [0,1] | [0,2] | [1,0] | [1,1] | [1,2] | [2,1] | [2,2]
  [0,0] | [0,1] | [0,2] | [1,0] | [1,1] | [1,2] | [2,0] | [2,2]
  [0,0] | [0,1] | [0,2] | [1,0] | [1,1] | [1,2] | [2,0] | [2,1]
```

I tried the following code but it doesn't work

```
public class CreateMatrix {
    // function to remove an element
public static int[][][] remeveaction2(int[][][] arr, int index, int[] ar) {
    int[][][] arr2 = new int[arr.length - 1][][];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i == index) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++) {
                    if (arr[i][j][0] == ar[0] && arr[i][j][1] == ar[1])
                        System.arraycopy(arr, 0, arr2, 0, j);
                    // copy from z+1 to end
                    System.arraycopy(arr, j + 1, arr2, j, arr.length - j - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return arr = arr2;
}
    
  }
```

If you have any idea please help me.
Thank you

**EDIT**

I tried the following code ;

```
public static void remeveaction(int[][][] arr,int index, int[] ar) {
    
        
            int [][] rowX = arr[index];
            int[][] replacementRow = new int[rowX.length-1][];
            int k = 0; 
            for(int i = 0;i<rowX.length-1;i++) {
                    if(!Arrays.equals(rowX[i], ar)) {
                         replacementRow[k++] = rowX[i];
                }
            
            arr[index] = replacementRow;
    }
    }
    // For test 
     int [] action = new int [] {0,2};
    int index = 3;

    remeveaction(actions,3,action);
    // Afichage;
    for (int[][] arr : actions) {
           System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
        }
}
```

But I get the following output:

```
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
[[0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], null]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 2]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1]]
```

Why the last element is null ? it must be [2,2]

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this. First you need to remember that multi-dimensional arrays are just arrays of arrays of arrays ...

So to remove the particular array you need to specify the `row` and `column` as they might be referred to in this example.

```
public static void remove(int r, int c, int[][][] vals) {
    // get the array (row) that contains the element to be removed.
    int[][] rowX = vals[r];

    // allocate a new replacement array, one element shorter
    int[][] replacementRow = new int[rowX.length-1][];
    
    // k is index of new row.
    int k = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < rowX.length; i++) {
        if (i != c) { // or if current index == element to delete, skip it.
            replacementRow[k++] = rowX[i];
        }
    }
    // now put replacement row back to current slot of old row.
    vals[r] = replacementRow;
}
```

The element in question is in row 6, column 2 as shown in your example. so if `vals` is the name of you matrix then call it as follows.

```
remove(5,2,vals); // row 6 is really row 5 since arrays are 0 based.
```

An easy way to verify it is to print it like so:

```
for (int[][] arr : vals) {
   System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
}
```

The method above is very basic.  It is up to you to put in checks to ensure that the specified indices are within the bounds of the array and to ensure the passed array is not `null`, etc.

Comment: but I do not know beforehand in each column there is the element that I want to delete, I have only one table that I must compare it with all the columns of the row and then extract the row without the element deleted

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason it's not working is because the lines making the array copy function are not cleaning up and/or resetting the array at the last position.
In other words, your code is overlaying:

```
  [0,0] | [0,1] | [0,2] | [1,0] | [1,1] | [2,0] | [2,1] | [2,2]
```

with

```
  [0,0] | [0,1] | [1,0] | [1,1] | [2,0] | [2,1] | [2,2] | [2,2]
```

thus causing the last position to remain the old one, [2,2], so the resulting array will be:

```
[0,0] | [0,1] | [1,0] | [1,1] | [2,0] | [2,1] | [2,2]
```

There are several ways of improving this code, one of them would be to copy the contents of arr[i] (which is a subarray with 2 dimensions, i.e. b[][]) into a brand new array arr2[arr.length - 1 - 1][2] (using the System.arraycopy() functions, like you're doing in your code) and then replace arr[i] with arr2 doing:

```
arr[i] = arr2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem.

The code that I used :

```
public static void remeveaction(int[][][] arr,int index, int[] ar) {        
            int [][] rowX = arr[index];
            int[][] replacementRow = new int[rowX.length-1][];
            int k = 0; 
            for(int i = 0;i<=rowX.length-1;i++) {
                    if(!Arrays.equals(rowX[i], ar)) {
                         replacementRow[k++] = rowX[i];
                }
            
            arr[index] = replacementRow;
    }
    }
     // for test 


    int [] action = new int [] {0,2};
    int index = 3;

    remeveaction(actions,3,action);

    // Afichage;
    for (int[][] arr : actions) {
           System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
        }
```

**Output**

```
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
[[0, 0], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 1], [2, 2]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 2]]
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1]]
```

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Considered accepting one of the answers that have helped you

Comment: @WJS This solution was based on your code?

Comment: @dreamcrash  Just partly.  I didn't know the op didn't know before hand which one to delete.  Nor was there any indication what to do if there were duplicates in the same "row".  So I based my solution on some assumptions.

Comment: @WJS something one has to make assumption ;)